# Evaluate %PATH% as the system-scope environment variable exclusively

Tags: windows-7, windows, environment-variables, path, cmd.exe

In Windows' command line, `echo %PATH%` appears to merge the system and the user variables `PATH` in such order before printing. That seems reasonable, but I would also like to be able to print only the system variable (or, alternatively, only the user variable).
Note that `echo` is just an example, I would expect it to work with any other command.

One can easily *set* either by using (or not) the `/M` flag when issuing the `SETX` command:

```
SETX PATH "D:\some\user\path"
^ sets the user variable PATH
SETX PATH "C:\some\system\path" /M
^ sets the system-wide variable PATH
```

But *evaluating* `%PATH%` in such manner doesn't seem as simple (or even possible). Simply typing in `%PATH%` results in:

```
C:\some\system\path;D:\some\user\path
```

Would it be possible to retrieve only `C:\some\system\path` (or only `D:\some\user\path`)?

I am aware of the existence of a GUI interface which lets one easily distinguish between the two. However, I'd like to achieve this task using only the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always query the registry values directly:

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2*" %a in ('reg query HKCU\Environment /v PATH') do @echo %b

for /f "skip=2 tokens=2*" %a in ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PATH') do @echo %b
```

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2*" %a in ('reg query HKCU\Environment /v PATH 2^>NUL') do @echo %b` to avoid _ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value_ (note `2^>NUL`). Moreover, could remove `skip=2` as it's being superabundant for this case (but still important for `HKLM` query)

Comment: @JosefZ: Yes, I glossed over the case where no user Path value exists. Instead of diverting it to NUL one can also easily test for the error returned and branch off accordingly in a batch file. Also, when the user Path exists, `skip=2` is required to get only the value without anything extra.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2*" %a in ('reg query HKCU\Environment /v TEMP') do @echo "%b"` returns the only (and right) value as there is no 2nd token in the first two lines. Of course, could retain `skip=2` as a matter of general principle...

Comment: @JosefZ: "returns the only (and right) value as there is no 2nd token in the first two lines" - Ah yes, you're absolutely right. Still, I prefer skipping over the non-required lines entirely so there is no ambiguity about which line I want to start processing from.

Comment: This works perfectly. But since it is somewhat complicated to type every time I would need it, I decided to wrap the command in a custom environment variable: `setx syspathdo "for /f \"skip=2 tokens=2*\" %a in ('reg query \"HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\" /v PATH') do @"`. Now I can simply issue `%syspathdo% echo %b`. My ultimate goal was to be able to extend the system path while keeping the user path always at the end, now it is easy: `%syspathdo% setx PATH "%b;C:\some\new\path" /m`. Thanks a lot!